# What links the names Oona, Albus, and Hymie?

Tags: knowledge

And now for something completely different:

**The names Oona, Albus, and Hymie share something in common.** Any suggestions?

Hint 1: Turkey Truck Driver can also be added to the list. So: **What do Oona, Albus, Hymie and Turkey Truck Driver share in common?**

Hint 2: Warren can be added to the list. So: **What do Oona, Albus, Hymie, Warren and Turkey Truck Driver share in common?**

Hint 3: A set of dates relevant to the names/identities is: **1964, 1966, 1985, 1994, and 2001 and 2002.**

Hint 4: A set of dates relevant to the thing shared in common is: **1968, 1969, 1969, 1972, and 1978.**

Comment: I'm just asking, what happened with the regular Ernie puzzles?

Comment: @Anonymus Ernie is currently in Kzijekistan. But, barring flight interruptions, I believe he will be back later this week. I will drop in on him then and see if anything interesting has happened during his absence.

Comment: Would [[tag:word-property]] be a relevant tag?

Comment: @bobble in this case I think not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pardon the brevity. I am exhausted from 2 days of sleuthing online. It was fun to watch it all come together though, when links on pages I was on suddenly began turning purple because I'd been on the other related pages hours or days earlier.

What do Oona, Albus, Hymie, Warren and Turkey Truck Driver share in common?

> These are characters played by musicians who performed a well received version of MacArthur Park, a famous song.  You can read about them here:
>  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacArthur_Park_(song)

Here is a synopsis of the key facts:

> - In 1968 MacArthur Park (MP) was recorded by Richard Harris who later played Albus in 2001 and 2002, in the Harry Potter movies.
>  - In 1969, Donna Summer received a Grammy for her version of MP. She later played Aunt Oona in a 1994 Family Matters episode.
>  - In 1969, Tony Bennett's cover of MP made it big. In 1966 he played Hymie Kelly in "The Oscar".
>  - In 1972, Andy Williams performed a popular version of MP. He had played Warren Palmer in 1964's "I'd Rather be Rich".
>  - In 1978, Waylon Jennings recorded a disco version of MP. He later played a Turkey Truck Driver in the 1985 movie "Follow that Bird".

Comment: Excellent sleuthing. What initially inspired me to creating the question was (a) the reputation of MacArthur Park as [the worst song ever written](https://www.theguardian.com/music/2007/aug/23/2) and (b) the image of Dumbledore singing it.

Comment: ...but only [third worst](https://www.rollingstone.com/music/music-lists/readers-poll-the-worst-songs-of-the-sixties-10986/3-richard-harris-macarthur-park-34668/) according to a Rolling Stone poll.